# android.os.networkonmainthreadexception in android, ICS

Tags: android

```
try {
    URL url = null;
    url = new URL(url_string);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line="";
    while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
        Log.d("html",line);
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("Exception Error: ",e.toString());
}
```

---

I am simply reading website and I am getting errors with android.os.networkonmainthreadexception

my code is very simple.. please take a look and please tell me what I need to do..

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

You need to move your network access into a background thread, such as via an `AsyncTask`. You are presently trying to perform network I/O on the main application thread, which is *not* a good idea.

Comment: +1 That's a good thing that android Android started to throw this exception, without it you will not see an issue until you have a slow network, and it will probably be the user to find it out...

Answer (score 0):

use this class to run background task..

```
    public class getConnection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> 
    {


           @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() 
           {
               super.onPreExecute();
               Utils.clearDialogs();
               Utils.showActivityViewer(Mainctivity.this);
           }

           @Override
           protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0)
           {

            try 
            {

               URL url = null;
url = new URL(url_string);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String line="";
while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
    Log.d("html",line);
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
             e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
           }

           @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
           {
               super.onPostExecute(result);
               Utils.hideActivityViewer();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
             Log.v("log", e.toString());
            }
           }

          }
```

Comment: I am sorry, I know I am very new on Android but I am not sure where the Utils class came from. Could you tell me where I should import the Utils class from? your code gives me that, cannot find Utils class.

Comment: I am actually still getting same networkonmain exception.
try{
      URL url = null;
      url = new URL(url_string);
      URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
      String line="";
      while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
       Log.d("html",line);
            }
     }catch (Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
i think it gets exception when conn.getInputStream() is called
any idea??